Can I use an AC SCR to control a 180 V DC motor?
I want to control the speed of a 180 V treadmill DC motor the cheapest and easiest way.
The motor will only run in one direction. It wil be powered by 220 V AC.
Can I use an AC SCR speed controller and add a bridge rectifier after it to control the DC motor, or do I need a different approach for this DC motor?


Did you check the motor isn't a universal motor? You wouldn't need any rectifier.

Your suggestion is cheap and it will control the speed. If it is good enough for your application then fine.
Low speed may be a bit bumpy, the motor may buzz due to 100 Hz and  harmonics there of. The speed regulation will not be that great either. Sure, PWM is better but will cost more.
If your performance is borderline then consider a dual time constant dimmer which will help but does not cost much more.
Next consider placing additional inductance on the AC side of the motor like for example a lamp 50 Hz ballast rated for the job. When I have done the lamp ballast trick it has been with smaller motors and has stopped audible noise.
You have to try this and see if it is good enough for you.
